# Building a selector with literals and variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a variable whose value is the same as an ID on the page. When I do this:

```
var foo = 'value';
$('#' + foo).thing();
```

it doesn't work. But this does work:

```
var foo = 'value';
var bar = '#' + foo; //'#value';
$(bar).thing();
```

How can I build that selector in a single line? Creating extra single-use variables seems wasteful.

Comment: That should work. Can you post your actual code?

Comment: Proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/JVxRX/

Comment: @hooked is right - something *outside* the question is affecting this if it's not working.

Comment: Perhaps `#value` doesn't exist? Or perhaps `$.thing()` is broken?

Comment: Looks like the problem was in the variable, which I had manipulated and then got confused about. I was adding an @ (I'm building a Twitter list), and it was reading the ID as #@value, which is illegal.

Comment: Thanks for all the help -- I've had this issue before, so I'll go back to variable-building camp and keep my manipulation paths clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User error -- I had an '@' in the variables (working on a Twitter thing), so the resulting ID was '#@value' which is illegal because of the @. Fixed that, and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. I've never had the problem. But perhaps you can try just adding another set of brackets around your inner statement: 
`$(("#" + foo)).something();`
If im not offtrack, this might force javascript to "calculate" the inner brackets first, before passing it into the jQuery selector function. Goog luck...

Comment: Nope...actually I just tested it and it works fine to dynamically gen a selector string. Make sure you declared the variable holding your selector string cause if you use the wrong name, JavaScript will just create a new empty string and try to use this as the intended variable, which would obviously fail. If you copy the your code, I'll have a look...